# Which one is best for view 3D model in Flash? PV3D or Away 3D- (no need animation stuffs, only need 3D quality)

Tags: flash, 3d, papervision3d, away3d

I am going to do a web 3D project.

In this project I am not going to do any animation -- instead I want to show 3D models. So those 3D models should be very good quality.

Which program is more suitable for my purpose PV3D or Away3D? I have tried PV3D, but the model that I imported from 3Ds Max as DAE is not look good; it looks like cartoon image. Any suggestion?

Please share your experience and provide me some links.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know papervision isnt under development anymore, so i would suggest away3d. It has an active community. if you target flashplayer 11, you can use Stage3D, that makes use of your GPU, which should deliver you the best 3d quality.

Answer (score 0):

To view the model I'm using an easy tool provided by Alternativa platform.
just import your model.
[a3dplayer](http://a3dplayer.com/)